# How to animate two patches concurrently in python pyplot animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to animate concurrently two groups of patches on my chart. For example Ellipses and Arrows. I can do this separately but not at once.I use pyplot animation, FuncAnimation.

I obtain the following error:

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1199, in _init_draw
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

The code is as follows:

```
def initiate_chart(self, axes, title='Layout'):
    self.title = title
    plt.title = self.title
    self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(axes[0]['xmin'], axes[0]['xmax']), ylim=(axes[0]['ymin'], axes[0]['ymax']))
    elipses = [Ellipse(i, width=0.6, height=0.3, angle=0) for i in self.trajectory[0]]
    arrows = [Arrow(x, y, self.velocities[0][i][0], self.velocities[0][i][1])
              for (i, (x, y)) in enumerate(self.trajectory[0])]
    [self.pedestrians.append(self.ax.add_patch(elipses[i])) for i in range(len(elipses))]
    [self.arrows.append(self.ax.add_patch(arrows[i])) for i in range(len(arrows))]

def init_animation(self):
    [self.pedestrians[i].set_visible(True) for i in range(len(self.pedestrians))]
    [self.arrows[i].set_visible(True) for i in range(len(self.arrows))]
    return self.pedestrians, self.arrows

def animate(self, i):
    self.arrows = []
    for j in range(len(self.pedestrians)):
        angle = degrees(atan2(self.trajectory[i][j][0], self.trajectory[i][j][1]))
        self.pedestrians[j].center = self.trajectory[i][j]
        self.pedestrians[j].angle = angle
        self.arrows.append(self.ax.add_patch(Arrow(self.trajectory[i][j][0], self.trajectory[i][j][1],
                                 self.velocities[i][j][0], self.velocities[i][j][1], width=0.5)))
    return self.pedestrians, self.arrows

def do_animation(self, n_frames, n_interval):
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init_animation, frames=n_frames,
                                   interval=n_interval, blit=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `animate` function returns a tuple of 2 lists (since `self.pedestrians` and `self.arrows` are each a List).

The animate function should return a single list of artists.

you should try something like:

```
def animate(self, i):
    (...)
    artists = self.pedestrians + self.arrows # concatenate lists of artists
    return artists
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Works fine.

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is now answered, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left